# Advantage of multiple pod on same node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-scaling

I'm new with Kubernetes, i'm testing with Minikube locally. I need some advice with Kubernetes's horizontal scaling.
In the following scenario :

- Cluster composed of only 1 node
- There is only 1 pod on this node
- Only one application running on this pod

Is there a benefit of deploying new pod **on this node only** to scale my application ?
If i understand correctly, pod are sharing the system's resources. So if i deploy 2 pods instead of 1 on the same node, there will be no performance increase.

There will be no availability increase either, because if the node fails, the two pods will also shut.

Am i right about my two previous statements ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Pods on the same node are anyhow utilizing the same CPU and Memory resources and therefore are expected to go down in event of node failure.

But, you need to consider it at pod level also. There can be situation where the pod itself gets failed but node is working fine. In such cases, multiple pods can help you serve better and make application highly available.
From performance perspective also, more number of pods can serve requests faster, thereby dropping down latency issues for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How does the increase in pod number translate to faster request processing ? If the code is well designed, each request will be handled by a different thread anyway so there is no latency. Having two pods with half the system's resources (plus the pod overhead) seems less performant than a single pod with full resource and proper request processing

Comment: Yes, if code is designed well to handle multiple request processing then increasing number of pods will not give any significant benefits